# Trying to compare two string values with MYSQL query using PHP script

Tags: php

PHP is returning false even though the value I enter is matching a value contained in MYSQL database. If I changed the query to using LIKE

' where team_name LIKE '".$id."%' ' - this returns something as it is comparing values similar in my database but this is not what I want to achieve. What I'm looking for is an exact match.

```
<?php


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){
require_once('db_connect.php');
searchTeams();

}


function searchTeams()
{
global $conn;
$id = $GET['pwd'];





$query = "Select password from team where password ='".$id."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$tmp_array = array();

if($number_of_rows >0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $tmp_array[] = $row;
    }
}


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("Team"=>$tmp_array));
mysqli_close($conn);
}


?>
```

Comment: "php is returning false"? Which line is returning false? What value did you expect?

Comment: I expected the password back

Comment: What line? What are the contents of the database? What input did you pass in? Without more detail it's impossible to help

Comment: Why you use this kind of tricky query's ? you can make it a lot more sample and more proper !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for logical operator '==='

Answer (score 0):

You should prepared the String to be read from DB, try this:

```
$query = sprintf("Select password from team where password ='%s' ", mysql_real_escape_string($id));
```

Comment: Why don't you use prepared statement when giving others advices ?